# Sorting objects by array.count in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, class, sorting, object

I have a class of Users and another for Devices:

```
class User {

var userId: Int
var userName: String
var location: String
var devices = [Device]()

init(user_id: Int, userName: String, location: String, devices: [Device]){

    userId = user_id
    self.userName = userName
    self.location = location
    self.devices = devices
}}

    class Device{

var deviceId : Int
var type: deviceType
var operating_system: operatingSystem
var userId: Int
var description: String
var inventoryNumber: String

init(device_id: Int, type: deviceType, operating_system : operatingSystem, userId:Int, description: String, inventory_num: String ){

    self.userId = userId
    deviceId = device_id
    self.type = type
    self.operating_system = operating_system
    self.description=description
    inventoryNumber = inventory_num
    }}
```

And I instantiated some objects from this class, I will paste just one line of it here:

```
var userArray = [User]()
var user1 = User(user_id: 1, userName: "John", location: "ClujNapoca",            devices: [device1, device2])
```

I have a total of 10 users appended in the array with different number of devices and i want to sort them by the number of devices they have. I have tried a lot and didn't managed to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this (to sort in ascending order):

```
userArray = userArray.sort({ $0.devices.count < $1.devices.count })
```

Comment: I tried this one, I have an error: Cannot assign value of type () to a value of type (User)

Comment: I tried another way, by declaring a variable in the class to count the devices in the arry, and named it deviceCount, but the error is the same:  http://prntscr.com/8p629w

Comment: your problem is "userArray = userArray.sort"  You can't assign the array to it self in this way in swift.

Comment: your problem is "userArray = userArray.sort"  You can't assign the array to it self in this way in swift. An easy solution in swift 2 is to use use userArray.sortInPlace(.....) or you can assign it to an new variable.

Answer (score 0):

`.sort` is your friend.

To reduce the problem:

```
struct User {
    var name: String
    var numberOfDevices: Int
}

var users = [User]()
users.append(User(name: "Mark", numberOfDevices: 4))
users.append(User(name: "Tom", numberOfDevices: 55))
users.append(User(name: "Jerry", numberOfDevices: 10))
users.append(User(name: "Rex", numberOfDevices: -5))

var sortedUsers = users.sort({ $0.numberOfDevices > $1.numberOfDevices })
print(sortedUsers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution:

```
var array: [[Int]] = []
.. some code
array = array.sorted(by: { $0.count < $1.count })
```